# detecting lines in matlab using houghlines

Tags: matlab

What I am trying to achieve is this
https://sites.google.com/a/vt.edu/motion-vision/home/license-plate-detection-by-hough-transform
I'm through detecting hough lines. But I cannot understand the procedure after this step
"Now, by setting the ratio of height and width, possible horizontal and vertical pairs are found to indicate those line segments around the license plate. The result is shown as in Figure 4." ..Somebody explain to me or adding the code would be helpful.

My Code:

```
clc
RGB = imread('new.jpg'); %Load image
[I2, rect] = imcrop(RGB);
I  = rgb2gray(I2); %Convert image to Gray
%imshow(I); %Show image


BW = edge(I,'canny');
%imshow(BW);

[H,T,R] = hough(BW);
imshow(H,[],'XData',T,'YData',R,...
            'InitialMagnification','fit');

xlabel('\theta'), ylabel('\rho');
axis on, axis normal, hold on;
P  = houghpeaks(H,20,'threshold',ceil(0.1*max(H(:))));
x = T(P(:,2)); y = R(P(:,1));
plot(x,y,'s','color','white');


lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',20);
figure, imshow(BW), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
      xy_long = xy;
   end
end
%[I2, rect] = imcrop(I);
%figure, imshow(I2);
```

Comment: Sorry for not attaching image.But any license plate from back end of the car would do.

Comment: This is not a matlab question. By the way, it means assuming you know the aspect ratio of a License Plate in real world, you just check all possible pairs of lines found in your Hough Line step and only keep those pairs with approximately same aspect ratio.

Comment: But where do I compare those lines and my aspect ratio.I'm new to using Hough Lines and Matlab.